# How to run a python script with a cron job?

Tags: python, cron, cron-task

I am running the latest OS. I have a python script. For now, I have placed it on my Desktop, and I can run it without a hitch.

The first line of my python script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

My cron job is:

```
*/1 * * * * Desktop/email_me.py
```

The error I get sent in the mail is:

```
/bin/sh: Desktop/email_me.py: Permission denied
```

In line with another StackOverflow answer, I edited my cronjob to:

```
*/1 * * * * chmod -X Desktop/email_me.py
```

Whereupon my mail becomes:

```
chmod: Unable to change file mode on Desktop/email_me.py: Operation not permitted
```

Please help! I don't know much about all this, please answer as if you were talking to a complete novice.

Comment: is the owner user of script as same as the user you created cron job with?
your cron job user must be the same or root!

Comment: @mjrezaee this will sound so stupid to you :D , but I'm on my own personal mac, have one user, and that user made both the script from scratch and added the cronjob line. How do I set the cron job user?